# Remove legend background when using geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, legend

I am making graph in ggplot and would like my key to have no background color. I am able to remove the background color with the following code because of the last line, legend.key=element_blank():

```
#For Testing
ggplot(data= Data, aes(x = Date, y = Elev, group = Well, colour = Well)) +
geom_line(size = 0.75) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Elevation (ft.)") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 year"),
               date_labels = ("%b %Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.key=element_blank())
```

However, I'd also like to shade certain parts of my graph using geom_rect. The problem is, when I add lavender shading in certain areas of my graph, the legend background becomes lavender. In fact, it seems that for every lavendar box I make with geom_rect, the legend background becomes a darker shade of lavender... The following code is the code above plus my geom_rect commands:

```
ggplot(data= Data, aes(x = Date, y = Elev, group = Well, colour = Well)) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2003-08-11", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2003-08-14",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2004-04-29", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2004-12-20",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2005-04-07", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2005-12-12",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2006-04-21", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2006-12-08",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2007-03-27", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2007-12-03",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2008-04-09", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2008-11-28",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2009-05-11", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2009-11-26",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2010-04-10", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2010-10-10",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2011-04-19", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2011-11-18",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2012-04-12", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2012-11-14",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2013-05-09", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2013-11-12",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2014-05-23", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2014-12-01",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2015-04-10", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2015-11-28",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2016-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2016-12-31",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lavender", 
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_line(size = 0.75) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Elevation (ft.)") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 year"),
              date_labels = ("%b %Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.key=element_blank())
```

Can anyone help me remove the lavender background from my legend? Here is the head of the code:

```
           Date            Well   Elev
1    2002-05-23            MW-3 929.04
2    2002-05-29            MW-3 929.39
3    2002-05-31            MW-3 929.37
4    2002-06-05            MW-3 929.36
5    2002-06-12            MW-3     NA
6    2002-06-13            MW-3 929.47
7    2002-06-19            MW-3 929.42
8    2002-06-26            MW-3 930.02
9    2002-07-05            MW-3 930.00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rid of the lavender background in the legend by adding `inherit.aes=FALSE` inside `geom_rect`. I also wanted to point out that you can vastly reduce the amount of code needed for your graph. Rather than separate calls to `geom_rect` for each pair of dates, you just need to have one vector of `xmin` dates and one vector of `xmax` dates in a single call to `geom_rect`. For example:

```
Data = data.frame(x=as.Date(c("2005-01-01", "2010-01-01")), y=c(5,6), group=c("A","B"))

rect.data = data.frame(xmin = as.Date(c("2003-08-11","2004-04-29","2016-04-01")),
                       xmax = as.Date(c("2003-12-14","2004-12-20","2016-12-13")),
                       ymin = -Inf, 
                       ymax = Inf)

ggplot(Data, aes(x, y, colour=group)) +
  geom_rect(data=rect.data, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),
            fill="lavender", linetype=0, alpha=1, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Also, if you can formulate explicit criteria for determining the start and end dates for the shading, then you can pull the dates directly from your data programmatically, rather than having to hard-code them by hand.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. The `inherit.aes = FALSE` did the trick. Regarding your second point about vastly reducing code-- thank you for this tip. I knew there had to be a simpler way! However, when I set up my dataframe of rectangle dates, and run my ggplot code as you have done above, I get a plot without any rectangles. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and the code you're running. It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing the exact code and data. Post a data sample by pasting into your question the output of `dput(data_sample)`.

Comment: I'm sorry @eipi10,  I'm new to Stack Overflow, and a sample of data/my code is too long for a comment... where should I post it?

Comment: Try to create a small data sample, maybe 10 rows or so, that exhibits the problem you're having, and post that and the code you're running. To post the data sample, paste into your question (into the body of your question, not into a comment) the output of `dput(data_sample)`.